# Compile Error: variable not defined (VB6)

Tags: vb6

Hi I'm trying to link a database from Access to VB6. Then I tried to display the contents of a record from the database in a table form using ListView. I have checked both References and Components needed but I keep getting the same error. It says Compile Error: variable not defined for the header of this code:

```
Sub dbconnection()
connect.Open "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
Data Source = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\werk\LAST SEM!!!!!!!!\CSC301\Foot-it!\ftsdb.mdb"
End Sub
```

I have already declared Option Explicit at the top of the code as shown here:

```
Option Explicit
Dim connect  As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
```

I'm really new to this and honestly I just looked this up on Youtube. Any type of help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: If you need more details just comment and I'll edit for your clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is because the 'Data Source' bit needs to be part of the previous line.  You're supposed to open a connection by specifying both the connection driver and the parameters in the open statement.

Try this:

```
connect.Open "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\werk\LAST SEM!!!!!!!!\CSC301\Foot-it!\ftsdb.mdb"
```

Comment: Here's an ADO reference showing the proper formatting of an open command, for instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524771(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\werk\LAST SEM!!!!!!!!\CSC301\Foot-it!\ftsdb.mdb"
```

"Data" used to be a reserved word in earlier versions of BASIC.

I don't work with SQL much, but I'm guessing what you wanted to do was something more like:

```
connect.DataSource = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\werk\LAST SEM!!!!!!!!\CSC301\Foot-it!\ftsdb.mdb"
```

or

```
rs.DataSource = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\werk\LAST SEM!!!!!!!!\CSC301\Foot-it!\ftsdb.mdb"
```

Others in here with more ADO experience might be able to confirm which, if either, is the correct one.

> EDIT:  Please refer to Luke G.'s answer, as it is the correct answer. 
>   Mine, though marked as accepted, I realize is incorrect.

Comment: I appreciate your marking my answer as accepted, but I think Luke G. probably better deserves it.  Mine was only a guess, and likely an incorrect one at that.  His appears to be the correct answer (it did stir my memory from when I used to use ADO).  You should mark his as the accepted answer.